# How to populate a listview from a datatable

Tags: asp.net, listview, datatable

I have a `ListView` and a `DataTable` and I would like to know how to populate the `ListView` from the `DataTable`.

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");
SqlCommand ccmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT img FROM '" + user + "'", conn);
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ccmd);
da.SelectCommand = ccmd;
da.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have already designed your ListView (and bindings inside it) in your markup here is the code you need in your server side to load data into listView:

```
listView.DataSource = dt;
listView.DataBind();
```