# convert json array to datatable asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, json.net

Please i am very new to json. I have a url which i pass values and the data returned is in json. I need to deserialize the json from this url and then bind it to a list view control in asp.net. This is what the json data looks like.

```
   {"records":[{"record":{"Ch_ID":"27","User_id":"1","Ch_Name":"test1","Ch_Description":"test1description","Ch_Starttime":""}},{"record":{"Ch_ID":"29","User_id":"1","Ch_Name":"w","Ch_Description":"ww","Ch_Starttime":"12"}},{"record":{"Ch_ID":"30","User_id":"1","Ch_Name":"qq","Ch_Description":"qqqdescription","Ch_Starttime":"1222"}},{"record":{"Ch_ID":"31","User_id":"1","Ch_Name":"v","Ch_Description":"vv","Ch_Starttime":"1"}},{"record":{"Ch_ID":"32","User_id":"1","Ch_Name":"n","Ch_Description":"nnnn","Ch_Starttime":"111"}}]}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how I can do this. I have tried out json.net but it is giving me errors.

Comment: this is the error that i get Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'wireframes.wcodes[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please can you update your question with the C# that you are using to do the deserialisation.

Comment: Please include the code you tried that gave you the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.NET does support deserializing a `DataTable` via its built-in [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs), however it expects the JSON to be formatted as an array, as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Ch_ID": "27",
    "User_id": "1",
    // Other fields
  },
  {
    "Ch_ID": "29",
    "User_id": "1",
    // Other fields
  },
  // Other records
]
```

Your JSON is instead formatted as follows:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "record": {
        "Ch_ID": "27",
        "User_id": "1",
        // Other fields
      }
    },
    {
      "record": {
        "Ch_ID": "29",
        "User_id": "1",
        // Other fields
      }
    },
    // Other records
  ]
}
```

You can translate your actual JSON into the format required by Json.NET by using a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
public class RecordDataTableConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            var token = JToken.Load(reader);
            token = new JArray(token.SelectTokens("records[*].record"));
            using (var subReader = token.CreateReader())
            {
                while (subReader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
                    subReader.Read();
                return base.ReadJson(subReader, objectType, existingValue, serializer); // Use base class to convert
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
var json = GetJson();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new[] { new RecordDataTableConverter() },
};

var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json, settings);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZvwJFQ).

Comment: thank you very much, i just tried this out and i get this error: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: @StanleyEkpunobi - I tested it with the json you provided and it works.  See the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZvwJFQ).  If that is not your real JSON, or you are not deserializing using the converter as shown in the answer, then please provide a [mcve] reproducing the problem.

Comment: ok it works fine now thank you very much. it is converting it to the actual json format. so how do i deserialize it to a string or any datatype that i can bind to a control.

Comment: @StanleyEkpunobi - As for binding a `DataTable` to a list view in asp.net, you could try [How to populate a listview from a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487421/how-to-populate-a-listview-from-a-datatable).